# TextField swiftui xcode 13

Tags: swiftui, xcode13

I have been working with xcode 12 and swiftui. In my app I have textFiel with a localizable placeholder in Spanish and English, I switch to xcode 13 and it doesn't show me my localizable placeholder

[image]

this only happens in TextField, with SecureField it does not happen even with Text

this is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var email:String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack () {
           TextField("login5", text: self.$email)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50).stroke(Color("grayColor")))
        }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

Localizable.strings

```
"login5" = "Correo eléctronico";
```

Comment: can you show a complete example of the text code (not a picture of bits of code) 
that you are using and the Localizable.strings file.

Comment: @workingdog I updated my code

Comment: this is not a  complete example of code that can be use to test your particular issue. Include the file name you use for the localizable strings.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem on my setup macos12, xcode 13-beta5 (not release), target ios15.  However, I've update my answer with a possible approach. If that still does not work, try using xcode 13-beta5 instead of xcode 13 release, works well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `SecureField` in ios15, you can use the prompt parameter to get your localized string:

```
SecureField("purpose", text: $password, prompt: Text("login6"))
```

or using the label:

```
 SecureField(text: $password) {
     Text("login6")
 }
```

EDIT1:

This is the test code I'm using to show a working localized TextField and SecureField.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @State var isVisible = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Button(action: { isVisible.toggle() }) {
                Text("Toggle isVisible")
            }
            TextField("login5", text: $email).border(.black)
            if isVisible {
                TextField("login6", text: $password).border(.green)
            } else {
                SecureField("password", text: $password, prompt: Text("login6")).border(.red)
            }
        }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

Test `Localizable.strings` file.

```
"login5" = "hola login5";
"login6" = "contraseña";
```

EDIT2: alternative approach of manually using LocalizedStringKey,

```
TextField(LocalizedStringKey("login5"), text: $email)
```

Comment: In SecureField I haven´t problem, is in TextField

Comment: Its not working with your textfield? 
And the textfield is only showing when visible is set on true?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code I use for testing. Does this work for you?

Comment: @workingdog I do, but nothing only appear "login5"

Comment: what system and target are you using? I'm using macos 12, xcode 13-beta (not RC), target ios15, macCatalyst and macos 12. Tested on real devices and simulator.

Comment: @workingdog macos 11.6 , xcode 13.0 release,  target ios15. Tested on real devices with ios 15 and ios 14 and simulator

Comment: Yeah, there are so many different ios/macos/xcode combinations that bring up 
so many different behaviours and bugs. It's a real dog's breakfast.
Maybe someone with a setup like yours can confirm the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your main Problem is, like workingdog already said, you need to use text: $variable.
That means for you declare your variable as  @State var password = "" and use it like this..

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var password = ""
    ...
    if self.visible{
        TextField("login6", text: $password)
        ....
    } else {
        SecureField("login6", text: $password)
        ....
    }
}
```

Btw. next time post your code as code not as picture. Its easier to help you :)
Hope I understand your problem correctly and this will be your solution.

Comment: the problem is only with TextField  

***TextField("fe8Sub", text: $caesareanFem)***

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem, going from Xcode 12 to 13. All of a sudden some (not all) of my text fields no longer show localized string. I was able to fix the problem by forcing:

`TextField(LocalizedString("usernameLabel"), text: $username)`

Instead of

`Textfield("usernameLabel", text: $username)`